# IPTABLES Forwarding issue

Tags: networking, iptables, ip-forwarding

Ok, so I am terrible with iptables so I need some help. Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a lan box on vlan 4 (172.16.9.65)
I have another box on vlan 9 (10.1.0.1)

My gateway for my 172.16.9.65 is a linux firewall and has to remain so.
Gateway/Firewall( 172.16.15.254 )

I have another box with two interfaces, one on each vlan.
Other box (eth0 172.16.9.8 ; eth1 10.1.0.2)

So my flow is like this

Desktop goes to 10.1.0.1 on port 80

Desktop(172.16.9.65)vlan4 --> GateWay/Firewall(172.16.15.154)vlan4 --> OtherBox(ETH0:172.16.9.8_vlan4 --> ETH1:10.1.0.2_vlan9) --> 10.1.0.1_originl destination.

I want to do this with iptables rules on two boxes
Gateway/Firewall
OtherBox

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with something like this:

Add a route on your gateway (or your desktop)
`route add -host 10.1.0.1 gw 172.16.9.8`

Add a rule like this on the OtherBox
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i eth0 -s 172.16.9.65 -d 10.1.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: Thanks, I like where you are going here but It did not work, here is what the windows box route looks like (desktop)

  `Active Routes:`
  `Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway         Interface`
  `0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         25.0.0.1      25.19.90.56`
  `0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    172.16.15.254      172.16.9.65`
  `10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       172.16.9.8      172.16.9.65`

Comment: Is ip forwarding allowed on the OtherBox?
Check `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

And what is in the FORWARD chain? You may have to add a rule like this if your forwarding policy is not ACCEPT

`iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.16.9.65 -d 10.1.0.1 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I got it, you da man!

Comment: Hey I have another similar issue.